# flex layout - unequal width of the material cards upon resizing the browser window

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am displaying cards dynamically.For e.g. 3 cards in each row which have equal width. When I resize the browser window, the width of the card is not uniform. Some of the cards are displayed in different width sizes.For e.g only one card in first row and in second row two cards with unequal width.

```
 Expected result : 1. cards to be displayed in 3 columns with equal width (large screen)
2. cards to be displayed in 2 columns with equal width  (medium screen)
3. cards to be displayed in 1 column with equal width  (mobile phone)
```

What are the possible values I need to set for flex layout in order to display uniformly upon all the screen sizes?

These are the versions used

```
Angular version - 2.4.10
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.2",
"@angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.5"
```

This is sample code

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap  style="padding-bottom: 15px; 
 padding-top: 15px;  margin: auto;justify-content: center" >  
<md-card fxFlex.gt-md="30" fxFlex.md="30"  fxFlex.sm="auto" fxFlex.xs="100" *ngFor="let data of myArray" style="margin:5px;">
          <md-card-content>
            <h1></h1>
            <h2></h2>
           <h2></h2>
          </md-card-content>
          </md-card> 
        </div>
```